# C# Windows Service which acts as TCP server refuses connection under Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, service, tcp, socketexception

I'm working on a simple pair of TCP server and client, which are running on the same machine.
As long as the server runs as ordinary executable, everything works. But as soon as I deploy the server as Windows service the client keeps getting SocketExecption stating "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6692".

I am fairly new to Windows 7, but I assume that there are some security restriction I am not aware of. Test wise I already deactivated the virus scanner as well as the firewall, which changed nothing.

Could anyone give me an hint?

Comment: can you telnet to this service from the same machine the service is running on?

Comment: Check the authorizations of the user that is running the service. Set this user the same authorizations that has the user that successfully ran the application as ordinary executable to see if the problem comes from here.

Comment: +1 - one of my current projects has an intraweb GUI, (Delphi, not C#, but..), and must run as a service when delivered. I hope I don't get this as well :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure that the service is actually running, that it did not stop after started.
2) Change the user under which the service is running (4ex to Local System)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did not pursue the topic further, as Telnet could not reach the service as well. I guess the problem was like @ken2k said.
I solved the problem by deploying the application as simple WinForms project that is only visible as tray icon. That way the communication workes.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same application core running in a console application (working OK) was not working as windows service (TCP communication problems).

Diagnostic: there were some nuget packages missing in windows service project. Those nuget packages already been installed for console application project.